# How to make addEventListener sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, event-handling, synchronization

when window loads div with a class preload doesnt disappear with transition 0.5s; it disappears immediately. I want to first disappear with transition 0.5s then add display none

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      $('.preload').css({
         'opacity': '0',
         'transition': '0.5s'
      });
   });
   $('.preload').css('display': 'none');
```

Comment: can I see  the  html?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to create a [MRE] with all of the relevant code to reproduce the problem, so we can see what is going wrong and be able to help.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the shortest way to achieve that. `fadeOut` is a jquery method, which creates an animation, for fade effect, and sets `display` to `none`, when the element gets faded completely. The parameter is the time for `transition` in `milliseconds`.

Check `fadeOut` here : [fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  $('.preload').fadeOut(500);
});
```

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}

.preload {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preload"></div>
```

Comment: @SamandarYusupov I am glad I could help. Don't forget to upvote and mark answer correct. Happy coding :)